# query with timestamp condition works in php but not working in laravel raw query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I have run the following query in PHP its works well.

```
SELECT * FROM transactions LEFT JOIN actions ON transactions.id_transaction_id = actions.id_transaction_id where transactions.server_datetime_trans >= '2017-11-07 12:00:00' AND transactions.server_datetime_trans <='2017-11-07 12:59:59'
```

but the same query i tried to run in laravel. its not working, always showing `empty array()`

2 types of Laravel code tried:

**TYPE 1::**

```
$data=DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM transactions LEFT JOIN actions ON transactions.id_transaction_id = actions.id_transaction_id where transactions.server_datetime_trans >= '2017-11-07 12:00:00' AND transactions.server_datetime_trans <='2017-11-07 12:59:59'"));
print_r($data);
```

**TYPE 2::**

```
$data=DB::select("SELECT * FROM transactions LEFT JOIN actions ON transactions.id_transaction_id = actions.id_transaction_id where transactions.server_datetime_trans >= '2017-11-07 12:00:00' AND transactions.server_datetime_trans <='2017-11-07 12:59:59'");
print_r($data);
```

both are displaying `empty array()` as result

Comment: can you try 
DB::select(DB::raw( "........" ) );

Comment: he already did? check type1

Comment: yep, I just saw that my bad :)

Comment: Are there anny Laraval errors?

Comment: There is no errors. showing empty array()

Comment: That means your query is OR not right, OR your query does not get results. Try to make your query smaller to see if you can get the variable filled with data at all. When you get data within your variable you know it's the query which need to be edited.

Comment: Query was running fine in normal php mysql. Only problem is laravel. If any one have different syntax for same query pls share.